# ios - Multiple Delegates for a ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a ViewController that acts like a Container for two VCs. This class is called MasterDetailViewController. Is a Custom View Controller Container. The MasterDetailViewController can communicate to either the Master or the Detail View Controller so they know status of for example: "Animation of showing detail ViewController started", "Visible rect for VC" and messages like that. The problem is that I need different methods for a master and different methods for a detail.

Is it ok to have two protocols:
`MasterViewControllerDelegate`
`DetailViewControllerDelegate`

And the MasterViewController has two properties delegateM and delegateD each conforming to each protocol?

I ask this because the delegate pattern is a 1:1 relationship and I ve never seen it used like this.

Thanks

Comment: How different are the two protocols? I ask because it is common to include the sender object in a delegate call argument so that the delegate can behave differently for different senders.

Comment: Today there are 2 common funcs for both and a different one specifically for each one. I could "merge" them and do your approach. So I keep one protocol and send the sender VC and the delegate will only do sth if the sender's class is equal to him, right?

Comment: @MichaelL I gave it a little more thought but this approach wouldnt work. Actually what happens is that my MasterDetailViewController needs to notify two different VCs of different actions that will happen. As well as he will need to be notified as well of things that happens to Master and Detail VCs...

Comment: OK, so what I do in that kind of case is pass a weak reference of the master controller to any of its sub-controllers. I don't call them delegates. A delegate protocol makes sense when a wide variety of classes can use the same delegate protocol. In this case, just call it like it is.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelL I like that solution. Put it as an answer so I can select it. I probably will do an extension to my UIViewControlBase (common class for all my UIViewControllers) and will find the parent that is type MasterDetailViewController or nil if their isnt one. Kinda of similar approach! Tks for the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in this kind of case is pass a weak reference of the master controller to any of its sub-controllers. I don't call them delegates. A delegate protocol makes sense when a wide variety of classes can use the same delegate protocol. In this case, just call it like it is.